# GridView control in ASP.NET is displaying data from DataSet, but Columns collection is EMPTY, so can't access/change any properties

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview

I'm teaching myself C# in VS2012 on 4.5 framework and loving it, but this is (continuing to) baffle me, so I apologize if I'm missing something obvious. I have done some new testing (since my original post 3/23) and am now more confused.

I added a DataSet item to my project called reviews.xsd.

I programmatically fill the DataSet with all data from Review table, then add two new fields to the Columns collection, then use EntityFramework to join to the Book table to add the data for those two new fields. I programmatically link the GridView control (dgvReviews) to this populated DataSet and everything displays great when I open the page, so all the data population into the DataSet and the linked GridView control is working great.

HOWEVER, the Columns collection of the GridView control is strangely EMPTY, so I can't change the styles of the columns or hide or show them using the Visible property. The Columns collection of the DataSet that populates the GridView is complete those values are accessible normally.

I have set numerous Watches to look at other properties of the GridView control and they seem to be populating normally: the Rows collection, for example, displays the values through the Watch window, but all access to the Columns collection displays "Enumeration yielded no results," even though the data is all displaying correctly (when I don't try to access the Columns collection explicitly in code).

I'm a beginning programmer so any advice would be much appreciated.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
    // create reviews dataset, populate with standard data from Review table
        reviews reviewDataSet = new reviews();
        reviewsTableAdapters.reviewTableAdapter reviewDataAdapter = new reviewsTableAdapters.reviewTableAdapter();
        reviewDataAdapter.Fill(reviewDataSet.review);
        reviewDataSet.review.Columns.Add("bookName", typeof(string));
        reviewDataSet.review.Columns.Add("bookDescription", typeof(string));
        reviewDataSet.review.Columns["bookName"].SetOrdinal(3);
        reviewDataSet.review.Columns["bookDescription"].SetOrdinal(4);

        // use EF to populate data from Book table into new bookName and bookDescription fields
        bookReviewsEntities bookConnection = new bookReviewsEntities();
        foreach (reviews.reviewRow reviewEntry in reviewDataSet.review)
        {
            int bookNumber = reviewEntry.bookID;
            var bookLookup = (from book in bookConnection.books
                              where book.bookID == bookNumber
                              select book).ToList();
            reviewEntry.BeginEdit();
            reviewEntry["bookName"] = bookLookup[0].title;
            reviewEntry["bookDescription"] = bookLookup[0].description;
            reviewEntry.EndEdit();
        }
        bookConnection.Dispose();

        // next 2 lines verify the Columns collection of the DataSet is working fine
        string test1 = reviewDataSet.review.Columns[0].ToString();
        string test2 = reviewDataSet.review.Columns[1].ToString();

        dgvReviews.DataSource = reviewDataSet.review;
        dgvReviews.DataBind();

        // everything runs and displays normally if next line is commented out
        dgvReviews.Columns[0].Visible = false; // crashes with "index out of range" since "Columns" collection is empty
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the Columns property to be accessible you need to list your columns in your GridView declaration like below and disable the auto generation of columns with AutoGenerateColumns="false"

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField ="Id" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField ="First" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField ="LastName" />
</Columns>
```

When Columns are auto generated you can't access the Columns property.